# Fragment - how can getActivity() return null AFTER onAttach

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a manager class which is a retained fragment and it holds not retained fragments and AsyncTasks of this fragments.

After screen rotation, I want to link the new fragments and the running/finished tasks with each other and update the fragments with the data provided by the task.

Now in my retained fragment I have following code:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    mFragStatePagerAdapter.update(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    
    Debugger.Debug(DEBUG, getClass(), "ON_ATTACH_0: parentActivity: {" + 
        (activity != null ? activity.hashCode() : "NULL") + "}");

    for (int i = 0; i < mFragStatePagerAdapter.getFragmentListSize(); i++)
    {
        Frag f = mFragStatePagerAdapter.tryGetItem(i);
        
        if (f != null)
            f.onAttach(activity);

        // alternatively I tried following as well
        // if (f != null)
        //     activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(f).commit();
        
        Debugger.Debug(DEBUG, getClass(), "ON_ATTACH_1: this: " + 
            this.hashCode() + " fragment: " + f + ", 
            parentActivity: {"+ (f.getActivity() != null ? f.getActivity().hashCode() : "NULL") + "}");
    }
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < mTasks.size(); i++)  
    {
        if (mTasks.get(i) != null)
        {
            Frag f = getFragment(i);
            mTasks.get(i).attach(f, mTaskCallbacks.get(i));
            if (mTasks.get(i).getStatus() == Status.FINISHED)
                mTasks.get(i).deliverResult();
        }
    }
    
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

For explanation:

- Frag... it's an class extending Fragment
- mFragStatePagerAdapter... it's an extended FragmentStatePagerAdapter with functionality to get fragments by index...

Now my problem is following (shortened) debug output:

> ON_ATTACH_0: parentActivity: {1123400376}
>
> ON_ATTACH_1: this: 1121944544 fragment: ExerciseViewFragment{42e2da98}, parentActivity: {NULL}

So why, after calling  `f.onAttach(activity)`, does `f.getActivity()` return null? I'm NOT overrideing `onAttach` in my extended fragment class, so this can't be the reason...

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to call `f.onAttach(activity);` yourself.

Comment: I added an alternative because that just brought me to following idea: using `activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(f).commit();` instead... but it did not work either unfortunately... so if `onAttach` shouldn't be used like that, how can I achieve my goal? The fragment should be attached to the new activity again... so that I can update the data of my fragment...

Comment: Something is fishy about your adapter implementation because those fragments should have a valid activity reference if they are the one currently visible in the ViewPager(calling onAttach yourself it's wrong). Anyway, instead of your retained fragment trying to send data to the other fragments why don' you make it a simple data holder and let the other fragments use it directly from their implementation.

Comment: Actually, I thought of this way as well... Now I have a retained fragment which holds the tasks and the pager fragments look in the retained fragment if a task exists and either attach themself to this task or if it already is finsihed use this tasks' data or create a new thread and add it to the retained fragment... This way everything seems to work so far... so thanks for pointing me in the right direction... spend the whole day with writing a reusable manager for pager + pageindicator + fragments which load their data in a thread... now I have something, so thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()

`getActivity()` may return null if the fragment is associated with a Context instead.

And as per this documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity), `onAttach(Activity activity)` is deprecated, so use `onAttach(Context)` instead.

Comment: that's true but only if you are using recent versions of Support Library. Question was asked in 2013 and back then it worked a bit different :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is with calling

`super.onAttach(activity);`

at the end of your `onAttach` method.
Call it as the first thing in this method, like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
     super.onAttach(activity)

     // and here goes your code
     [...]
}
```

Comment: I'm not using this code anymore but I remember that that was necessary. I had to that before. And the problem was not, that the retained fragment threw the exception, the manually attached fragments (you can see that in the code) were attached and DIRECTLY after did not return the activity they just had been attached to...